# Соответствует данная таблица правилам (1НФ, 2НФ, 3НФ) нормализации базы данных?

Tags: база-данных

Условие 1НФ:

1. Нет повторяющихся строк. [Условие выполняется] +
2. Все атрибуты простые. [Условие выполняется] +
3. Все значения скалярные. [Условие выполняется] +

Условие 2НФ:

1. Таблица находится в 1НФ. [Условие выполняется] +
2. У таблицы должен быть первичный ключ. [Условие выполняется] +
3. Все атрибуты должны описывать первичный ключ целиком, а не какую-то часть первичного ключа. [Условие выполняется] +

Условие 3НФ:

1. Таблица находится во 2НФ. [Условие выполняется] +
2. Не должно быть зависимостей одних не ключевых атрибутов от других. Все атрибуты зависят только от первичного ключа.[Условие выполняется] +

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Документ приложен: https://yadi.sk/i/cchOiG2hUqJR_A

Верно? Заранее спасибо)))

Comment: Нет эта таблица не находится даже во 2 нормальной форме!

Comment: 1нф - соотвествуйет же верно? А в остальных я был не уверен..